# How to get bit values from Byte?

Tags: c#, byte, bit, bitarray

I have a byte say 1 byte of elements of 8.. How do i get the bit each values? for example, I want 16th bit value, 17th bit, 18th bit so on..

```
    byte[] _byte = new byte[8];
```

Comment: You can't get the 17th bit, _byte have only 8 bits...

Comment: it has 64 bits... it is byte of size 8.. 8*8=64 know?

Comment: @ArnaldoBadin Incorrect

Comment: ok, sorry, i saw bit (thinked about bit_array), not byte.

Comment: There's no such thing as "a byte of size 8". A byte is a unit that has 8 bits. You could be talking about a `short` that has 16 bits, an `int` that has 32 bits, or a `long` that has 64 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [BitArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.100).aspx) constructor [BitArray((Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xda43a(v=vs.100).aspx) to get bits array from byte array. Use indexer on the bit array to get the required bit.

```
var bits = new BitArray(_byte);
```

Now bit 16 would be bits[15];

You can follow this example to understand how you can get the require bit.

```
byte[] _byte = new byte[3] {1,3,7};
var bits = new BitArray(_byte);
    for(int i=0; i < bits.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(bits[i]);
```

Output:

True present 1 at bit and false present 0 at bit

*First Byte* Value = 1 = 00000001 (Binary)

```
True   = 1            0 bit index 
False  = 0            1 bit index   
False  = 0            2 bit index
False  = 0            3 bit index
False  = 0            4 bit index   
False  = 0            5 bit index
False  = 0            6 bit index
False  = 0            7 bit index
```

*Second Byte* Value = 3 = 00000011 (Binary)

```
True   = 1            8 bit index 
True   = 1            9 bit index   
False  = 0            10 bit index
False  = 0            11 bit index
False  = 0            12 bit index   
False  = 0            13 bit index
False  = 0            14 bit index
False  = 0            15 bit index
```

*Third Byte* Value = 7 = 00000111 (Binary)

```
True   = 1            16 bit index 
True   = 1            17 bit index   
True   = 1            18 bit index
False  = 0            19 bit index
False  = 0            20 bit index   
False  = 0            21 bit index
False  = 0            22 bit index
False  = 0            23 bit index
```

Comment: Summary:

var bits = new BitArray(new [] { _myByte });

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to work with bits you can use the [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) class. One of its constructor overloads lets you pass in a byte array. Also to note, the bit will be represented by a boolean with true repesenting '1' and false '0'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Xth bit in your Byte Array (I think that is what your asking at least), you need to index the correct Byte from the array and then extract the bit

```
public static Boolean GetBitX(byte[] bytes, int x) {
    var index = x/8;
    var bit = x-index*8;

    return (bytes[index] & (1<<bit)) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Boolean GetBitX(byte[] bytes, int x) {
    var index = x/8;
    System.Collections.BitArray ba = new BitArray(new byte[]{bytes[index]});
    return ba.Get(x);
}
```

You can use [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple method to it.

Example use:

A :10101010

B :1

Get the 4th bit from A, so you get B

getBit(A, 4);

```
//gets n'th bit from a byte, returns as an int
int getBit(byte b, int bitNumber) {
   return ((b >> bitNumber) & 0x01);
}
```